Euclid’s “Elements” Redux Callahan's Problem
I'm working through Euclid's “Elements” Redux by Callahan, but I'm having trouble understanding one of the exercises. It is worth mentioning that my native language is Spanish and I speak English intermediately, so I think that is part of the reason for the comprehension problem.
The exercise is 4 of preposition 1.32 on page 82, which says:

If two right triangles △ABC, △ABD are on the same hypotenuse AB and if the vertices C and D are joined, then the pair of angles standing opposite any side of the resulting quadrilateral are equal.

As for the pair of opposite angles on either side of the resulting quadrilateral, I don't know what they are. I can't locate them. I've looked into geogebra, but I can't find these equal angles. I don't want an answer to the exercise as such, I just want to locate what angles it refers to in order to develop the demonstration.

Just now I just saw which angles it could refer to. I suppose they are those that are formed with the pair of lines by extending two sides

On what page is this?

exercise 4 on page 80, Proposition 1.32 on pages 78-79. Diagram:  draw a circle with diameter AB, the midpoint of AB is the center of the circle.  Point C is somewhere on the circle, point D is some other point on the circle

I remembered that I had asked this question, and I am going to take the opportunity to share the diagram that helped me. The angles to prove that they are equal are the $α$ and $β$, I think so.

